# external/svox/pico/src/com/svox/pico/PicoService.java (AOSP Default) try to run CTS but result fails in oero

Tags: android-source

I am trying to run CTS on default AOSP TTS engine . But still the cts is getting failed with the results
command to run CTS for speech
run cts --skip-device-info --skip-preconditions --disable-reboot --module CtsSpeechTestCases

Module                        Passed    Failed  Total Tests Done
x86 CtsSpeechTestCases          4          5    9           true
x86_64 CtsSpeechTestCases       3          6    9           true

onUtteranceCompleted(String utteranceId) not decepricated and in oero 
Use UtteranceProgressListener instead.

Module                        Passed    Failed  Total Tests Done
x86 CtsSpeechTestCases          4   5   9           true
x86_64 CtsSpeechTestCases   3   6   9           true

why there is failing with the aosp default TTS engine

Answer (score 0):

```
https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/external/svox/+/617406

Failed CTS cases:
android.speech.tts.cts.TextToSpeechTest#testSpeak
android.speech.tts.cts.TextToSpeechTest#testSpeakStop
android.speech.tts.cts.TextToSpeechTest#testSynthesizeToFile

We can also reproduce this NE by following steps:
1. Go to Accessibility Settings
2. Select Text to speech output
3. Click play

Analysis:
Exception occurs due to calculation of
picokpr_getAttrValArrInt32(...) is incorrect. The logic here
intends to clear the MSB and return the rest of the bits. We
found if library compiled in Android N environment the result
of comparison operation is different from library compiled in
Android O environment. In Android O, actual returne value doesn't
process the value and returns as it is. This causes invalid
pointer access and hence native exception due to segmentation fault.

Solution: Changed to use bitwise shift instead.

Bug: 64204643
Test: After applying this patch, CTS cases can pass and exception
can be fixed.

Change-Id: Ife3137225ecf9667df62321472420fab6ab88d2e
```